# Refactor C# selenium code to minimize the code duplication

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am fairly new the C# and selenium. I have successfully validated a scenario however there is lot of duplication involved. As I have only 4 languages to test in my test case it was easy. I would like to know how do we approach if we have many languages to test. I 'm sure there should be an easy method. Can somebody help please. Please see below my code.

```
Browser.Driver.FindElement(By.Id("dropdownMenuLang")).Click();       
Browser.Driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//span[contains(., 'Espa')]")).Click();
Thread.Sleep(2000);
IWebElement body = Browser.Driver.FindElement(By.TagName("body"));
Assert.IsTrue(body.Text.Contains("Temperatura del frigorífico durante"));

Browser.Driver.FindElement(By.Id("dropdownMenuLang")).Click();          
Browser.Driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//span[contains(., 'Portu')]")).Click();            
Thread.Sleep(2000);            
IWebElement body1 = Browser.Driver.FindElement(By.TagName("body"));        
Assert.IsTrue(body1.Text.Contains("Gerenciamento De Serviços"));

Browser.Driver.FindElement(By.Id("dropdownMenuLang")).Click();            
Browser.Driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//span[contains(., 'Fran')]")).Click();            
Thread.Sleep(2000);            
IWebElement body2 = Browser.Driver.FindElement(By.TagName("body"));            
Assert.IsTrue(body2.Text.Contains("Gestion des emplacements"));

Browser.Driver.FindElement(By.Id("dropdownMenuLang")).Click();         
Browser.Driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//span[contains(., 'Türkçe')]")).Click();
Thread.Sleep(2000);
IWebElement body3 = Browser.Driver.FindElement(By.TagName("body"));
Assert.IsTrue(body3.Text.Contains("Konum Yönetimi"));
```

Comment: Your question is more related to "how to write reusable methods and code?" than selenium.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you mentioned you have **4** languages to test so you can write a `function()` as follows :

```
public void clickLang_assertContent(String lang, String text_to_assert)
{
    Browser.Driver.FindElement(By.Id("dropdownMenuLang")).Click();
    Browser.Driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//span[.='" + lang + "']")).Click();
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(Browser.Driver, new TimeSpan(0,0,10));
    IWebElement body = wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.TagName("body")));
    Assert.IsTrue(body.Text.Contains(text_to_assert));
}
```

Now, from your `main()` or `@Test` annotated Class you can call the function `clickLang_assertContent()` with the *options* which you want to validate as follows :

```
clickLang_assertContent("Espa", "Temperatura del frigorífico durante");
clickLang_assertContent("Portu", "Gerenciamento De Serviços");
clickLang_assertContent("Fran", "Gestion des emplacements");
clickLang_assertContent("Türkçe", "Konum Yönetimi");
```

Comment: Debanjan, Thank you for your response. I see an exception while debugging the code (System.ArgumentNullException: 'input cannot be null
Parameter name: input') in the line IWebElement body = new WebDriverWait(driver, new TimeSpan(0,0,10)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.TagName("body")))

Comment: There was an issue with `new WebDriverWait(Browser.Driver, new TimeSpan(0,0,10))` line, corrected it. Let me know the status please.

Comment: had tried this, but it gives a warning Can't convert from OpenQA.Sel.ISearchContext to OpenQA.sele.IwebDriver

Comment: Check once again with the updated code please and let me know the status.

Comment: it appears the same, my static Browser class was declaring the webdriver as private (private static IWebDriver _webDriver;  ) . I tried to change it to public, however the warning on Browser.Driver appears to be the same.

Comment: Debanjan, I got your concept. and the following code works perfectly. I will try to refactor again to remove the hard wait

Comment: Browser.Driver.FindElement(By.Id("dropdownMenuLang")).Click();
            Browser.Driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//span[.='" + lang + "']")).Click();
            //WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(Browser.Driver, new TimeSpan(0, 0, 10));
            Thread.Sleep(2000);
            IWebElement body = Browser.Driver.FindElement(By.TagName("body"));            
            Assert.IsTrue(body.Text.Contains(text_to_assert));

Answer (score 0):

A more organized way of handling this keeping in mind the flexibility to extend would be to use `classes` to define a `test case` like below:

```
public class TestCases
{
        public TestCases(string elementTag, string id, string xpath, string textToMatch)
        {
            ElementTag = elementTag;
            Id = id;
            XPath = xpath;
            TextToMatch = textToMatch;
        }

        public string ElementTag { get; set; }

        public string Id { get; set; }

        public string XPath { get; set; }

        public string TextToMatch { get; set; }

}
```

This class would handle all the properties that you need to play around with to change your `Assertions`.

You can write up a `List<TestCases>` to hold all your `values` for these test cases. This is the only thing that you'll need to change or add things here if you want to later extend your functionality. For example below:

```
List<TestCases> CurrentTestCases = new List<TestCases>()
{
    new TestCases("body", "dropdownMenuLang", "//span[contains(., 'Espa')]", "Temperatura del frigorífico durante"),
    new TestCases("body", "dropdownMenuLang", "//span[contains(., 'Portu')]", "Gerenciamento De Serviços"),
    new TestCases("body", "dropdownMenuLang", "//span[contains(., 'Fran')]", "Gestion des emplacements"),
    new TestCases("body", "dropdownMenuLang", "//span[contains(., 'Türkçe')]", "Konum Yönetimi")
};
```

And finally, you need a method to quickly execute the whole operation. You can do so with a simple `foreach` loop like below:

```
private void StartTesting()
    {

        foreach (var testCase in CurrentTestCases)
        {
            Browser.Driver.FindElement(By.Id(testCase.Id)).Click();
            Browser.Driver.FindElement(By.XPath(testCase.XPath)).Click();
            WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(Browser.Driver, new TimeSpan(0,0,10));
            IWebElement body3 = Browser.Driver.FindElement(By.TagName(testCase.ElementTag));
            Assert.IsTrue(body3.Text.Contains(testCase.TextToMatch));
        }
    }
```

> I've pulled out all the string hardcodings just incase you want that kind of flexibility, if you don't then you can reduce it by simply removing properties from the class.

Comment: Thank you for your response, I 'm trying the first answer where I could understand quickly, however I will definitely try your method as well. Thanks again.

Comment: @Aju Not a problem. I do understand that this is an overwhelming approach but in the long run to keep your code extensible (open to extension but closed to modification) this would be the ideal approach. Never the less, do upvote it if you like the implementation when you do try it